# It works great, but i don't understand a part of code [IMAGE UPLOAD]

Tags: php, image-uploading

Whats up coding community,
atm i'm learning PHP and i'm trying to make a little Image Upload script with a Image-Feed like "Instagram" or anything like this.

Today i've whatched btw. a great tutorial from 'Codecourse' and I scripted my code like he does. I really understand every part of his code except line 21 - 24.

I would be very grateful if anyone of youre intelligent Coding-Heads could explain these rows step by step.

I've commented out these rows.

```
if(isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['file'];

  //Datei Eigenschaften
  $file_name = $file['name'];
  $file_tmp = $file['tmp_name'];
  $file_size = $file['size'];
  $file_error = $file['error'];

  //File extensions
  $file_ext = explode('.', $file_name);
  $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));

  $allowed = array('txt', 'jpg');

  if(in_array($file_ext, $allowed)) {
      if($file_error === 0) {
          if($file_size <= 2097152) {

            //$file_name_new = uniqid('', true) . '.' . $file_ext;
            //$file_destination = '../uploads/' . $file_name_new;

            //if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination)) {
                  echo $file_destination;
              }

          }
      }
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: (I consider _monkey see, monkey do_ a valid way to start coding - just don't get stuck there.) Try and "format" your source code (consistently). (From eyeballing,) Your commenting introduced a syntax error. Consider using a spelling checker, don't overdo abbreviations (`Whats`, `atm`, `i'm`, `i've`, `whatched`…). Welcome to Stack Overflow! (where salutations & thanks are considered chit-chat to avoid)

Comment: Thanks greybeard, i will remember your words.

Comment: @ Fred -ii- i think that was an error, but it wasnt the only one.. if you want to look at my code again i undelete my old question.

*undeletet*

Comment: @ Fred -ii- cause my script doesnt work i have tried make a new one, but this time it should save the images to a folder on my server. I think you are an intelligent brain, so if you want you can look on it and say me whats  the fault before i make a new question and you answer it correctly :)

http://pastebin.com/Hu1CHztH

Comment: @Fred -ii- now it works i'vegot it myself. But thanks for youre help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> //$file_name_new = uniqid('', true) . '.' . $file_ext;
> //$file_destination = '../uploads/' . $file_name_new;
>
> //if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination)) {
>     echo $file_destination;
> ```

Is this the part you don't understand?

First line will define an unique id for your uploaded file and put the file extension on it. Something like `someuniqueID.png`. This is to make sure the file does not get a name that has already been taken by another file on the server. So `uniqid('', true)` will generate a random ID, while  `$file_ext` is the extension of the uploaded file(jpg, png, gif or something like that).

Next line is where you define where to store the uploaded file, in the code you choose to store the file in `../uploads/` and then use the new filename (`$file_name_new`) constructed in your first line (the unique name . extension).

The last `if statement` does two things, move the actual file to your location, using your unique name, and checks if it has been done. If it runs successful, it will `echo` out the full destination and new filename of your file.

Comment: Thank you very much Bolly, but one last question:
I know that the dots connect some elements, but why the code is like this : 

uniqid('', true) . '.' . $file_ext; ?

what does the 1st, 2nd and 3rd dot do?

Comment: @scythe The first and last "dot" is the way you combine strings in PHP. Say I have a $var1 = "hello"; and $var2="world"; then $var1.$var2 be "helloworld". So in this example, you combine 3 vars - først the uniqueID then "." that is the dot before the extension, and lastly the $file_ext. So you end of with randomID.extention. Does that make sense? 

Using the other example with $var1 and $var2, if I did $var3 = $var1.".".$var2; then $var3 would be "hello.world".

Comment: @scythe Great, remember to mark my answer as answer, if you feel it answered your question :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$file_name_new = uniqid('', true) . '.' . $file_ext;
```

$file_name_new will create a unique name for the image with the file extension.

```
$file_destination = '../uploads/' . $file_name_new;
```

$file_destination = is the new path where the image will be uploaded.

```
if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination)) {
              echo $file_destination;
          }
```

The above code will upload the image it sell to the new location.

Comment: Thanks, but this part of script i understand.

But i dont know how this uniqid function works, so what means that '.'?

     uniqid('', true) . '.' . $file_ext;

what it is doing here?

Comment: The '.' Is the extension seperator.

Comment: For example: '.'jpg (without the quotes)